# execute a command with environment variable set temporarily

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I used to use Bash, which has this syntax:

```bash
VAR=VAL ./executable_file
```

to set `VAR` temporarily during the execution of `executable_file`.

Is there a corresponding syntax in pwsh?

---

PowerShell 7.4.0 on MS-Windows

Comment: Are you asking how to define an environment variable in PowerShell?  

Comment: @Olaf No. I can run `$env:VAR=VAL` to set an environment variable, but I need to unset it after execution (and it will cover the original value, which is not what I'm expecting).

Comment: You should update your question with additional information - do not add it as comment. If you don't make it permanent the variable will be gone when the PowerShell session ends. Or you save the value temprorarily to an intermediate variable and restore the original value later on. There is no *shortcut* for that in PowerSehll that I know of.

Comment: @Olaf I see no need. My description of this question is pretty clear. No key information missing; no extra words

Comment: Someone downvoted this question?  Just because *you think* the description is not clear enough?  Should I change the original title "**execute a command *with environment variable set temporarily***"?  (Does anyone really not understand this title? )

Comment: As of v7.4, PowerShell has *no* support for child process-scoped environment vars. (e.g., `FOO=bar someutility …`). [GitHub issue #3316] (https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3316) is a request to support at least similar syntax. Current options: (a) Set env. vars. for the _current_ process, call the child process (which inherits them), then restore the env. (b) Call _via a shell_ (possible PowerShell itself) and set the vars. _there_ - you pay a performance penalty. (c) In v7.4+, you may use `Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait -Environment ...`  - you lose stream integration.

Comment: @mklement0 "... you lose stream integration." -- thx! I don't know this before. So I won't accept my answer because it is not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

After consulting the relevant documents, I found that `Start-Process -Environment @{VAR = VAL} --args ...` can achieve this.

```
$TEEEST=40
$env:TEEEST=41
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "emacs.exe" -ArgumentList '-Q', '--batch', '--eval', `(message`(getenv`(symbol-name`'TEEEST`)`)`) -Environment @{TEEEST = 42} -Wait
echo $TEEEST $env:TEEEST
```

Output:

```
42
40
41
```

---

Note:

1. It currently only works in `pwsh` (PowerShell Core) v7.4.
2. You can't capture stdout/stderr like what you do in Bash (e.g., `TEEEST=42 emacs -Q -nw --batch --eval '(print (getenv "TEEEST"))' > a.txt`).
   I tested this by

   ```
   Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "emacs.exe" -ArgumentList '-Q', '--batch', '--eval', `(print`(getenv`(symbol-name`'TEEEST`)`)`) -Environment @{TEEEST = 42} -Wait > a.txt
   ```

   As [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375) mentioned:

   > your only options are `-RedirectStandardOutput`/`-RedirectStandardError` to send output to *files*, with no direct ability to *merge* the streams.
3. The `$LASTEXITCODE` is not set. I tested this by

   ```
   echo $LASTEXITCODE
   Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "gcc.exe" -Environment @{TEEEST = 42} -Wait
   echo $LASTEXITCODE  # You may expect it to be 1 because gcc didn't receive arguments.
   ```

   output (omit the output of gcc)

   ```
   0
   0
   ```

Comment: Thanks for updating. Note that it will work in v7.4 _and all future_ `pwsh` versions, but it won't be back-ported to `powershell` (Windows PowerShell). The way to get the exit code is by adding `-PassThru` to the `Start-Process` call, which makes it output a process-info object whose `.ExitCode` property you can query. However, there's a bug that currently prevents this with `-NoNewWindow` - see [GitHub issue #20400](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20400#issuecomment-1740954070), which also mentions workarounds.